# Animate gridview items in sequence when added

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp

I would really like to have the `<AddDeleteThemeTransition/>` animate each element of my gridview in sequence. I'm using a custom class derived from GridView, which prevents me from simply using Task.Delay() when I'm loading the elements in my C#, because my gridview adapts the GridViewItem size according to the amount of elements. How  can  I achieve this?

Comment: If you can please post your custom class derived from GridView.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4JQu76Ej . It's a pretty standard pattern and shows up just like the gridview of the windows explorer. The problem is that if I set a delay as I add my items, the control will see there's only one item, and will give it all the available space. Then the second one pops up, and they each get half the available space, etc... It's pretty ugly.